# Why I can't get categories?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, sanity

Does anyone know why I can't filter out the categories?

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_key, _ref, _type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I also tried with {categories.title}

when implementing

```
                 {categories && categories.map((index, category) => (
                    <p key={index}>{category}</p>
                  ))}
```

it just shows 0 in all cards.

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import groq from 'groq'
import sanityClient from '../client'
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

function urlFor (source) {
    return imageUrlBuilder(sanityClient).image(source)
  }
  
  const stories = ({posts}) => {
      return (
        <div className='bg-gray-100'>
          <div className='md:grid md:grid-cols-3 px-4 py-4'>
          {posts.length > 0 && posts.map(
            ({ _id, title = '', slug = '', description, mainImage, categories }) =>
              slug && (
                <div key={_id} className='py-2 md:px-2'>
                <Link href="/post/[slug]" as={`/post/${slug.current}`}>
                <div className='border rounded-md p-4 bg-white cursor-pointer'>
                <img className='w-full' src={urlFor(mainImage).url()}
                  width='500'
                  height='500' 
                  alt="Mainn Image"/>
                  <h2 className='text-2xl py-6'>{title}</h2>
                  <p>{categories}</p>
                  <p className='opacity-60'>{description}</p>
                </div>
                </Link>
                </div>
              )
          )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
  
  export async function getStaticProps() {
      const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(groq`
        *[_type == "post" && publishedAt < now()] | order(publishedAt desc)
      `)
      return {
        props: {
          posts
        }
      }
  }


export default stories
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in your code is related to built-in `map` method of `Array` constructor. `map` 's callback function as a first parameter gets an array `value` and as a second an `index` of that array item. So you mixed up the order of callback function parameters.

Also you used a `category` value as a children for JSX element (in your case it's `<p>`), whose type is probably an object.

For example, if your category looks like this: `{id: 0, title: 'Books'}`, then you can use as a child or an innerHTML/innerText of `<p>` like this:

`<p key={category.id}>{category.title}</p>`,
but not like:
`<p key={index}>{category}</p>`